# How to detect auto-generated webpages by url

Tags: html, url, auto-generate

I was given a task to create sitemap by the given url in fsharp excluding auto generated webpages. By url I can load html document and search for all urls in it. Could you explain, what is basically auto-generated webpage and how can one determine that the webpage url leads to is auto generated? Thank you for the help!

Comment: "Could you explain, what is basically auto-generated webpage" - You should clarify that with the person who gave the task to you.

Comment: @moose I understand that but don't have an opportunity to do so. Being completely unfamiliar with html I must complete the task so I use all possible ways to get the information.

Comment: Did you really want to write that you are unfamiliar with HTML? What are you familiar with?

Comment: @moose briefly with Fsharp.Data library to work with html, fsharp itself and usage of google. That's almost enough to complete the task. The only thing I don't know is the answer to the question above.